# getElementById for XML Documents, Mozilla extensions

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox-addon, xpcom, xml-parsing

Is `document.getElementById` method supported on DOM parsed from XML strings using the DOMParser method in Mozilla?
I am making a Mozilla extension that reads an XML file and uses DOM Parser to convert the XML into a DOM element and tries getting elements by Id. The method getElementsByTagName works but not getElementById. It always returns null.

```
function (xmlString) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"); 
    var aNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("nodeTag");
    for(var i=0; i<aNodes.length; ++i) {
        var id = aNodes[i].getAttribute('id');
        var resultNode = doc.getElementById(id);
        alert(id);
        alert(resultNode);
    }
}
```

I tried the above code. alert(id) returns the proper id, whereas alert(resultNode) returns null every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `document.getElementById` doesn't generally work on arbitrary XML documents.

In recent browsers (e.g. Firefox 3.5 and later), you can use `document.querySelector` instead:

```
var resultNode = doc.querySelector("[id=" + id + "]");
```

Comment: Yes, but of course that returns attributes whose name is "id", not attributes whose type is ID.

Comment: @Michael: Indeed, but I suspect that may be good enough for the OP. Besides, does `DOMParser` read DTDs?

Comment: Extracted from w3 DOM-Level-2-Core documentation, "Note: The DOM implementation must have information that says which attributes are of type ID. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined. Implementations that do not know whether attributes are of type ID or not are expected to return null." so this is why it don't run as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like a solution that actually makes the getElementById() method usable (which you should, It is much much faster, and more versatile) and you have access to the DTD add the following line to it:

```
<!ATTLIST client id ID #IMPLIED >
```

If you aren't using a DTD yet, just add this to the xml document directly after the `<?xml version= \"1.0\"?>` statement:

```
<!DOCTYPE clients [ 
   <!ATTLIST client id ID #IMPLIED > 
]>
```

In this example "clients" is the root of my xml file, and "client" is the element i would like to attach id's to. You can add multiple "ATTLIST" statements for other elements you would like to add id's to other types of elements.

I tested this in safari, chrome, and firefox. works perfectly.

Comment: getElementById() wasn't working for me, either. @Michael Kay explained why. This fixed it for me. Thanks, @VoltzRoad!