# getElementsByTagName works but getElementById not working?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I am doing XML parsing and come upon a weird problem. The getElementsByTagName from a DOM element works, but getElementById doesn't. Chrome gives this error anywhere I call getElementById for the manifest:

```
Object #<Element> has no method 'getElementById'
```

But somehow getElementByTagName works just fine.

```
var manifest = content.getElementsByTagName("manifest")[0];
var spine = content.getElementsByTagName("spine")[0];
var itemref = spine.getElementsByTagName("itemref")[0].getAttribute("idref");
alert(itemref);//works
var firstpage = manifest.getElementById(itemref).getAttribite("href");
```

Can anyone please explain to me why the getElementById DOM is not working for me?

```
test = manifest.getElementById("any value");//Problem
test = manifest.getElementsByTagName("any value");//no Problem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `getElementById` as a method of arbitrary elements, it is only available on the `document` element. That makes sense, as there shouldn't be any duplicate IDs on an HTML document.

That being said, your call `getElementById("a")` looks strange; do you really have an element with `id="a"`, or are you trying to get a reference to an arbitrary anchor?

Comment: I am sorry for being vague. getElementById("a") should have been getElementById("any value") because it was just to explain that getElementById doesn't work and getElementsByTagName does. I will have to write my own getElementById function to accomplish this. I am paring an complex XML file with a DOM Parser.

Comment: So you'll need to accomodate duplicate IDs, is that the issue?

Comment: No there is no duplicate IDs within the XML and that is why I wanted to use getElementById but I did not know that it is not part of the DOMElement so I will have to write my own one.

Comment: I don't see why, as it should by available on the XML root element (isn't it?)

Comment: No accourding to this it is not:[DOMElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element)

Comment: You're right (or at least it was a problem in firefox once). This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3667520/825789

Answer (score 4):

getElementById looks for the unique ID of the element, not the type of element that it is.  As such, if your tag looked like the following, it would work for both scenarios:

```
<a id="a">
```

Comment: Sorry but you misunderstood my question. Content is a complex XML file, and not an HTML with <a> tags. I did not know that getElementById only belongs to the document Object, but getElementsByTagName to any DOM Parser object as pointed out by bfavaretto.

Answer (score 0):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) is a function of [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document) object. [DOMElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element) don't have this method.